# implementing maxperhour and maxperday

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

In my application there are incoming messages and I would like to sample some of them, for simplicity let's say 1 every 10. I have a settings file in which I have the following properties:

- MaxPerHour
- MaxPerDay
- MaxAllTime

It's not an option to keep the counts in the current class so I somehow need to store them (on database or memory).

Also an important thing is that there are multiple collectors, so I would need to be able to know how many Collector1 has collected in the last hour / this day. It's also in an async environment

I am out of ideas as I know that if I were to store this data in database it's would not be that performant.

Comment: I have no idea what you are expecting an answer to be.

Comment: The question is, how would you do this ? What methode/technique would you go for

Comment: There is some more context needed. This is an on-premise solution? Do you already have a database which could be utilized?

Answer (score 0):

It would be of value to know what your hosting environment is. I think a distributed cache may turn out to be your holy grail. You can share this instance over all your connectors and easily read/write/invalidate data over this shared instance.

For example, running your system in Azure, Azure Cache for Redis is awesome to solve your problem but then again, your infra is key to the correct answer.

Comment: But I need to take into account that the program could shutdown any moment, this will result in dataloss

Comment: You can persist the cache data so it continues at startup where it left off

Comment: Where can I find more information about that (data persisting)

Comment: If you're talking about Azure Cache for Redis in particular, then your information is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-how-to-premium-persistence. Talking about data persistence in general, then I think this question is outside the scope of your original question

Comment: But I would need to check the Redis for every incoming message, this would be too perfomance consuming.